# jQuery Sortable, variable losing value in onUpdate()

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following Sortable plugin:

https://github.com/rubaxa/Sortable

The code works fine for the most part. The problem I'm having, is with the **onUpdate()** callback. For some reason it always passes back the value "numbers" in `prompt`:

```
var items = {

    social: {
        // some variables, but not relevant to this test case
    },
    extra: {
        // some variables, but not relevant to this test case
    },
    media: {
        // some variables, but not relevant to this test case
    },
    addresses: {
        // some variables, but not relevant to this test case
    },
    numbers: {
        // some variables, but not relevant to this test case
    },
};

    for (var prompt in items) {
        if ($('#input_fields_wrap_'+propt+'_fields').length) {

            console.log("setting up sortable for " + 'input_fields_wrap_'+prompt+'_fields')
            Sortable.create(document.getElementById('input_fields_wrap_'+prompt+'_fields'), {
              animation: 150,
              onUpdate: function (evt) {
                console.log("FOO: "+ prompt)
                updateSortNumbers(pro,pt)
              }
            });
        }
    }
```

when you change the sort order, you always get:

> FOO: numbers

Even when you are sorting one of the other fields. I think it has something to do with the fact the order I'm initialising them is:

- social
- extra
- media
- addresses
- numbers

And because "numbers" is the last one, that always gets selected. Is there a way I can set a value on the Sortable element itself, to work out which one is being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally worked out how to do this. The trick was to grab the item in question with:

```
var item = evt.item;
```

Then `item` holds a value called `className`, so I can do:

```
var this_is = item.className.replace("-item","");
```

this them correctly holds the value I need. So the final working code was:

```
Sortable.create(document.getElementById('input_fields_wrap_'+propt+'_fields'), {
          animation: 150,
          onUpdate: function (evt) {

            var item = evt.item;
            // console.log(item.className)
            var this_is = item.className.replace("-item","");
            console.log("FOO: "+ this_is)
            updateSortNumbers(this_is)
          }
});
```